# How do I make the "potions" have a limit of 5?

Tags: python

I'm doing a battle simulator sort of thing, and I want the player to be able to use potions, which add health, a maximum of 5 times. I also want the player to be able to have the choice to choose different types of items, but those different items cannot be more than five. Here's what I have so far:

```
import random, sys, time
pokedex = {"Bulbasaur": [200,32,],
       "Ivysaur"  : [230,40],
       "Venusaur" : [270,50],
       "Charmander": [188,30],
       "Charmeleon": [226,40],
       "Charizard": [266,84],
       "Squirtle": [198,48],
       "Wartortle": [228,31],
       "Blatoise": [268,41],
       "Caterpie": [200,15],
       "Metapod": [210,10],
       "Butterfree": [230,22],
       "Weedle": [190,17],
       "Kakuna": [200,12],
       "Beedrill": [240,45],
       "Pidgey": [190,22],
       "Pidgeotto": [236,30],
       "Pidgeot": [276,40],
       "Rattata": [170,28],
       "Raticate": [220,40],
       "Spearow": [190,30],
       "Fearow": [240,45],
       "Ekans": [180,30],
       "Arbok": [230,42],
       "Pikachu": [180,27],
       "Raichu": [230,45],
       "Sandshrew": [210,37],
       "Sandslash": [260,50],
       "Nidoran♀": [220,23],
       "Nidorina": [250,32],
       "Nidoqueen": [290,46],
       "Nidoran♂": [202,28],
       "Nidorino": [232,36],
       "Nidoking": [272,51],
       "Clefairy": [250,22],
       "Clefable": [300,35],
       "Vulpix": [186,20],
       "Ninetales": [256,38],
       "Jigglypuff": [340,22],
       "Wigglytuff": [390,35],
       "Zubat": [190,22],
       "Golbat": [260,40],


       }
   enemy = random.choice(list(pokedex.keys()))
   enemy = [enemy, pokedex[enemy][0]]          
   player = random.choice(list(pokedex.keys()))
   player = [player, pokedex[player][0]]
   print("Your pokemon is: %s" % (player[0]))
   print("The enemy's pokemon is: %s" % (enemy[0]))

   while(player[1] > 0 and enemy[1] > 0):
       if pokedex[player[0]][1] < enemy[1]:
           choice = input("What would you like to do?")
           if choice in ["Attack","attack","Kill","kill"]:
               print("The player has attacked the enemy's %s." % (enemy[0]))
               enemy[1] -= pokedex[player[0]][1]
               print("The enemy's %s has %d HP remaining!" % (enemy[0], enemy[1]))
           if choice in ["potion","Potion"]:
                player[1] = player[1]+20
       else:
           enemy[1] = 0
           print("The enemy's %s has %d HP remaining!" % (enemy[0], enemy[1]))
           print("The player's %s has won!" % (player[0]))
           break
    if pokedex[enemy[0]][1] < player[1]:
        print("The enemy has attacked the player's %s." % (player[0]))
        player[1] -= pokedex[enemy[0]][1]
        print("The player's %s has %d HP remaining!" % (player[0], player[1]))
    else:
        player[1] = 0
        print("The player's %s has %d HP remaining!" % (player[0], player[1]))
        print("The enemy's %s has won!" % (enemy[0]))
        break
```

The formatting is a little weird, but I assure you that it works on my end, and the only thing that need is the potion problem above. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Initialize a counter outside the while loop, check that the counter is less than 5 when the player selects "potion", increment the counter by 1 each time a potion is used.

Comment: You're asking a question about potions, which means you're not thinking about the program. Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329207/it-says-that-it-is-a-string-but-it-is-all-integers) had a comment suggesting you create a [mcve]. This is a good practice to get better at thinking about your problem. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is to track how many potions have been used, and to use some sort of conditional (if/while) centered around comparing that value to 5. Something like:

```
     potions_used = 0

     if choice in ["potion","Potion"]:
         if (potions_used <= 5):
            player[1] = player[1]+20
            potions_used += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a player object which has a list of items that the player owns.
Create a method for adding items to that list. In this method, you can now check the number of items before adding them to the list.

```
class Player(object):
    __slots__ = ['items', 'potions']

    MAX_POTIONS = 5

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.potions = Player.MAX_POTIONS

    def use_potion():
        # Here you can check if the number of potions you have
        # has reached zero
        pass

    def add_item(item):
        # Here you can check the number of items the player has
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

keep track of a variable, "potionsUsed" or something similar, increment it each time a potion is used, when it hits 5, don't allow the player to use potions.

```
if (choice in ["potion","Potion"]) && (potionsUsed < 5):
            player[1] = player[1]+20
```

Something like that